# How can I mine continuously?

Tags: cpu-mining, smart-mining

Is there a way to keep "start_mining 2" mining continuously?  If so, what command can I use?  I started "start_mining 2" yesterday, left for work and came home and mining appeared to have stopped.  Thoughts?...

Comment: Is there an error log you can share so we know more about why mining stopped?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I don't remember the exact error message, but what happened is I typed "status" command from wallet and received a message stating that I was not synced...

Answer (score 2):

`start_mining 2` is supposed to mine continously.

Mining is paused at a few points, when modifying the blockchain. It is possible that a bug crept in, causing mining to not get out of pause. A bug report on https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues will be help in getting this fixed.

In the meantime, you can have a simple cron job restarting mining through RPC, like this:

`curl -v -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/start_mining -d '{"miner_address":"insertyouraddresshere","threads":2}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`